# How to flip the image inside an svg horizontally?

Tags: svg

I have the following svg image and I want to flip the image horizontally. How can I do that? Already tried adding scale(-1, 1) to some of the transform statements, but it does not seem to work.

Note: The svg is an export from sketch, so it might be a little strange formatted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="645px" height="470px" viewBox="0 0 645 470" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path d="M38.5969948,-2.22080132e-11 C16.8456745,30.2125678 3.07305242,70.3781435 0.923015792,123.840504 C-7.15396842,324.681101 174,465.890038 341,469.890015 C508,473.889991 658.942386,367.295224 643.971193,180.147362 C637.875363,103.946248 607.401187,44.0482171 563.7625,-2.35331754e-11 L38.5969948,-1.42108547e-14 Z" id="path-1"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Bitmap">
            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
            <image mask="url(#mask-2)" x="-800" y="0" width="1867.94872" height="470" xlink:href="http://www.castleknockhotel.com/cmsGallery/imagerow/5904/resized/1600x400/cycling_passion_of_life_high_resolution_wallpaper_for_desktop_background_download_cycling_images_free.jpg">
            </image>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Note: I only want to flip the image, and don't want to flip the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaah... I found a solution. I needed to wrap the image and add the mask to the container. Then transform the image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="645px" height="470px" viewBox="0 0 645 470" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <path d="M38.5969948,-2.22080132e-11 C16.8456745,30.2125678 3.07305242,70.3781435 0.923015792,123.840504 C-7.15396842,324.681101 174,465.890038 341,469.890015 C508,473.889991 658.942386,367.295224 643.971193,180.147362 C637.875363,103.946248 607.401187,44.0482171 563.7625,-2.35331754e-11 L38.5969948,-1.42108547e-14 Z" id="path-1"></path>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Bitmap">
            <mask id="mask-2" fill="white">
                <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
            </mask>
            <g mask="url(#mask-2)">
                <image x="-800" y="0" width="1867.94872" height="470" xlink:href="http://www.castleknockhotel.com/cmsGallery/imagerow/5904/resized/1600x400/cycling_passion_of_life_high_resolution_wallpaper_for_desktop_background_download_cycling_images_free.jpg" transform="scale(-1 1)">
                </image>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scale use the origin of the coordinate system.
If you want to scale it in the center of the Image, you have to translate middle of the Imgage to the origin, then scale, then translate back:

Add the attribute:

```
transform="translate(tx,0) scale(-1,1) translate(-tx,0)"
```

With tx = PositionOfImageX + WidthOfImgage / 2

Note: Transform  process from right to left, so it starts with translate(-tx,0)